# Expect command with multiple commands

Tags: expect

Since I have issues with my remote server [authorized_keys...] I wrote a script on my local machine that uses `expect` command to ssh into the server and then perform `cd` and then `git pull`

But I can't get this thing to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh USER@IP_ADDRESS   
expect {
    "USER@IP_ADDRESS's password:"  {
        send "PASSWORD\r"
    }
    "[USER@server ~]$" {
        send "cd public_html"
    }
}   
interact
```

Do I need to escape some chars? even when I try it still ignores the `cd` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[` is special to TCL so will need proper handling, either via `"\[quotes]"` or by replacing the quotes with curly braces `{[quotes]}`. A more complete example would look something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

set prompt {\[USER@HOST[[:blank:]]+[^\]]+\]\$ }
spawn ssh USER@HOST

expect_before {
    # TODO possibly with logging, or via `log_file` (see expect(1))
    timeout { exit 1 }
    eof { exit 1 }
}

# connect
expect {
    # if get a prompt then public key auth probably logged us in
    # so drop out of this block
    -re $prompt {}
    -ex "password:" {
        send -- "Hunter2\r"
        expect -re $prompt
    }
    # TODO handle other cases like fingerprint mismatch here...
}

# assuming the above got us to a prompt...
send -- "cd FIXMESOMEDIR\r"

expect {
    # TWEAK error message may vary depending on shell (try
    # both a not-exist dir and a chmod 000 dir)
    -ex " cd: " { exit 1 }
    -re $prompt {}
}

# assuming the above got us to a prompt and that the cd was
# properly checked for errors...
send -- "echo git pull FIXMEREMOVEDEBUGECHO\r"

expect -re $prompt
interact
```

Comment: nice answer. You might want to distinguish between the timeout and eof cases with a different exit status.

Comment: Wow! works great! note sure I get the expect_before thingie but thanks!

Comment: I just added another send -- "exit\r" in the end to disconnect, works perfect!